# How install Ubuntu to notebook without [bootable cd-rom,usb,( Smart Boot Manager), or pxe] using floppy?

Tags: ubuntu, bootable-media

Welcome,

I would like use my old notebook as ssh client.

I was trying to install Ubuntu but BIOS don't have boot option from CD, because drive is build in docking station.

I have network card 10BaseT, but don't have boot rom...

I create bootable floppy with Smart Boot Manager, and run it from my notebook.
I get recognize cd-rom, but when i want boot from them, i got "read error".

CD drive is working 100%, now i'm installing windows ME using win98 bootable disk.

Maybe someone know other boot manager on floppy drive what allow to install Ubuntu ?

Regards

Comment: Can you boot from USB?

Comment: I don't have USB port :(

Answer (score 1):

[gPXE](http://etherboot.org/) lets you use PXE on a machine that doesn't have a PXE ROM.

Comment: But i don't want download all image from TFTP. I have cdrom drive, but  i have to "kick" setup from floppy.

Comment: Why not? TFTP will be orders of magnitude faster than loading from floppy, and appreciably faster than CD, even over 10Base-T.

Answer (score 0):

Put a grub4dos MBR + grldr onto fat32-formatted diskette (use grubinst_gui, offered at http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/grubinst/grubinst%201.0.1/grubinst_1.0.1_bin_win.zip/download )

Then, boot it and from grub4dos's console:
chainloader (rd0) // or other drive. Ubuntu's CDROM.
boot

You can also boot ISO's or use PXE from within G4D.

Grub4dos distro is available: http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/GRUB4DOS/grub4dos%200.4.4/grub4dos-0.4.4.zip/download  ; more recent loader build is @ http://download.gna.org/grub4dos/